# Subscript out of range when setting workbook that is already open

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to select and work with a workbook that is already open.

After obtaining the name through a userform, when I try to set the workbook, or interact with it otherwise, I get a subscript out of range error.

I have confirmed the workbook is open, and that the ExcelAp object is connecting to the right instance of Excel.

```
Option Explicit

....

Public Sub TerminalOpen()
Dim WorkbookOpen        As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim ExcelAp             As Excel.Application
Dim FedExWkbk           As Excel.Workbook

....

Else
    Set ExcelAp = Excel.Application
    WorkbookSelection.Show
    WkbkFedExTracking = Trim(VBA.Left(WkbkFedExTracking, InStr(1, WkbkFedExTracking, ".", vbTextCompare) - 1))
    Set FedExWkbk = ExcelAp.Workbooks(WkbkFedExTracking)  <<<<< This is where the error occurs
    FedExWkbk.Activate
End If
```

I tried late-binding the ExcelAp. This approach seems to have worked in other instances, but not in this one.

The workbook name is stored in the WkbkFedExTracking string.  It is cleaned up to just the name of the workbook without the .xlsx portion. Also, on debug I've checked that against the name of the open workbook, and it is correct.

Comment: Double check if WkbkFedExTracking the name of one of the open workbooks.

Comment: It is, sorry for not being clear about that upfront.  I added it in the edits just a moment ago.  I am 100% certain it is the appropriate workbook name.

Comment: What is the actual name of the workbook? I noticed you are using `InStr` which will find the first . instead of `InStrRev` which will find the last .  So if the workbook name is `This.is.a.workbook.xls` then your code would get `This` instead of `This.is.a.workbook`

Comment: Also, there's no need to remove the extension anyway, so maybe that is causing issues in the first place.  Does it work without the prior line?

Comment: +1 @tigeravatar there is no need to remove the extension.  If I remove the extension, I replicate the error `Subscript out of Range`.  Leave the extension on the filename.

Comment: @tigeravatar There are no dots in the workbook title but I'll be removing this anyway pursuant to your suggestion because I just got it to execute by walking through it and adjusting some things.  It seems as though I'm getting a second instance of Excel somewhere and binding to that, thus causing the subscript out of range nonsense.  I'm attempting to track down the source of this now.

Comment: The error is not pursuant an instance of Excel, it's raising an error because the Workbooks Collection references the workbook by `.Name` or index, and the `.Name` contains the file extension. YOu need to leave the extension in the filename when setting a workbook variable.

Comment: @DavidZemens The issue seems to be both droping the extension and a second instance of excel.  I've got it sorted now.  Here's what happened:  I kept switching back and forth on the extension, I swear I've had to remove it before or removed it and had it work.  I'm leaving it on now.  However, what I also had occuring was a stray Excel.Application.Visible = True line was creating a second instance of excel, which was buggering things up as well.  Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: @user2761919 +1 to you then, good job resolving your own question!

Comment: @DavidZemens Hey, you guys helped.  I'd have gotten nowhere with the .xlsx dropped.  It was a collaborative effort.

Comment: That's what we're here for :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved.  It was a combination of a dropped .xlsx extension on the index name of the workbook as well as a stray instance of excel due to a poorly placed application.Visible = true line.  See the comments on the original post for more details.